# F2 Visa - Universities that offer online Master's in CS

Tags: visa, student-visa

I am on an F1 visa in the United States working at Amazon as a software engineer in Seattle. I am going to get married in 2 months. My partner would come on F2 visa. She is a software engineer in India. She has to leave her job and we are trying to find some employer if they could offer her an H1B visa here.

We tried for quite some time and did not find any. So, we thought of another way to get the job for her in US. That is, she could complete a master's in CS here and then she can work on F1 after graduation. So, we are trying to find some master's options, which could be either off campus or in Seattle itself, since we do not want to live separately.

Also, if the master's is for a year or something, that would be another advantage. So, can someone recommend me universities that would be best for my wife:

1. Offer good computer science course (good ROI).
2. Not very expensive master's.
3. Either provides online course or in Seattle.
4. If, of short duration (like 1 year or something), that would be a bonus.

Any suggestion you can give would be greatly appreciated.